# How to stop this kind of thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one thread that has this code

```
while(!this.isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        socket = server.accept();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

When I call interrupt method from somewhere then it will stop executing only if it is checking condition. What if the program is at server.accept() statement? It will not stop till any request comes from any socket. I want that when I call interrupt method this should stop immediately. Is there any solution for this problem.

Comment: No. You would have to `close()` the `socket`. `ServerSocket` uses uninterruptible IO.

Comment: Okay thank you. But how to detect at accept() statement that this thread was interrupted?

Comment: what if you call `stop()` on your `Thread`-Object? Will it interrupt `server.accept()`? i know the method is deprecated.

Comment: @JohnnyAW this method is deprecated with good reason. **NEVER** use it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider like i said, i know it is deprecated, just wondering, if it would interrupt `server.accept()`

Comment: @JohnnyAW it will kill the `Thread`. It would not allow are locks to be released or any resources to be freed. It might well break the socket and that port irrecoverably.

Comment: @BoristheSpider from javaDocs: "Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to UNLOCK all of the monitors that it has locked". This is the difference to `destroy()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `interrupt()` method in your Thread like this:

```
@Override
public void interrupt() {
    super.interrupt();
    socket.close();
}
```

When another thread interrupts this thread, the socket will get closed. When the thread is currently inside `accept()`, accept will exit immediately by throwing a `SocketException`. Your catch-block will catch that exception (`SocketException` is a subclass of `IOException`) and the check in the while-statement will be performed, which will then notice that the `isInterrupted()` flag is set and exit.

In contrary to the currently accepted solution it will exit immediately and not wait for up to 10 seconds to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a timeout on your ServerSocket:

```
server.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

When you call the accept method now, it will accept new connections for 10 seconds, after that it throws a SocketTimeoutException. Then you can do your accept again.

Comment: I think this is a bad solution - it can take up to 10 seconds for the thread to exit that way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use the deprecated [`destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy%28%29) method to <strike>stop</strike> *brutally murder* the thread, but you really shouldn't do that because you don't know what it is doing at that moment. Chances are the accept-method is currently in the middle of some operation which must not be interrupted without cleanup.

A better solution would be to call `server.close()` from another thread. In that case the accept will exit by throwing a `SocketException`.

To allow another thread to do this, you either need to expose a reference to your server-socket somehow, or you need to add a public method to your Thread-class which can be called from another thread and which then calls `server.close()`. The best obtion depends on how the code around the snippet you posted looks.

Comment: hmmm, i don't think `server.close()` from other Thread is a good idea, because you would need another Thread that would check for interrupt condition...

Answer (score 0):

You could extend ServerSocket and override the implAccept() method to instead have a timeout and check for the interrupt flag.

Or you could create another thread that monitors the parent thread status and closes the socket when you interrupt it.

```
public void close()
           throws IOException
Closes this socket. Any thread currently blocked in accept() will throw a SocketException.
If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed as well.
```